# How do I separate the date from the string

Tags: javascript

`This is a string 2011-11-09 00:00:00`
So now how do I separate the date i.e. 2011-11-09 from the string, I dont want to use the slicing here if anyone has better options or ideas please let me know..

Comment: I have just tried slicing. And I cant use that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var date = '2011-11-09 00:00:00'.split(' ')[0];
```

Comment: @kapilchhattani Ok ;) Any reason why you absolutely not want to use slice? `'2011-11-09 00:00:00'.slice(0, 10)`

Comment: Well the string is pre-sliced sometimes when it comes from the database, so lets say i might get 2011-11-9 instead of 2011-11-09 so zeros in the first place of a date and month are sliced off even before i get them..

Answer (score 2):

You can split it by `' '` and then the first element will contain what you want.

```
console.log('2011-11-09 00:00:00'.split(' ')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var date = 'This is a string 2011-11-09 00:00:00'.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use splicing, like you posted you could create a Date obj

```
 var newDate = new Date(2011-11-09 00:00:00);
```

then to get the date, just use the toString override

```
 var dateOnly = newDate.toString("YYYY-mm-dd");
```

That is if you dont want to use splicing or splits

Comment: Where did you see that `toString` took a format as argument?

Comment: @DWolf I already got the solution but I will try yours as well just to learn something new.. Upvoted.. thank you..